# Newby Question: Meshes rotating transforming unexpectedly

Tags: modeling, transforms

I have a model that I have been working on for weeks.

Blender has now started to behave unexpectedly (to my eyes!)... and I do not know where to look for 'the' setting!

When I rotate a mesh ... some other meshes are rotating as well. This is not related to parenting (AFAIK). I have even added a new mesh to the model ... rotated this new mesh and a 'seemingly random' selection of other meshes start rotating as well. Not all of the other meshes are rotating, just 3 or 4.

As you can imagine ... frustrating since I cannot see what has changed.

Where should I look to fixing this?

Thanks.

Additional Info:

I have just selected a parent object that has always worked as expected. Now when I drag the object along an axis ... the child objects move along that same axis ... but at different rates ... thus loosing their alignment with the parent.

I am certain this is an obvious UI box somewhere :-) rather than some sort of data corruption!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it seems you have coincidently activated *Proportional Editing* (shortcut: <kbd>O</kbd>). This lets you translate other objects (or vertices in *Edit Mode*) proportionally in distance to the selected object(s). The radius of influence can be changed with the scroll wheel.

[image: proportional editing]

Comment: Thank you ... my life in now restored !

Comment: @Folbo You could accept the answer to thank me ;)

Comment: There is a time limit to thanking ... and accepting (probably since I was editing my question as you replied) ... but a huge and genuine THANK YOU. :-)

Comment: There is a time limit? Didn't know that. Maybe because I get distracted and do something else before looking again into a question... :D